# How do I have to declare copyright on my Website?

Tags: html, copyright-display

I have a Javascript, Html and Css Website and have some Pictures that aren't mine.
Now I have the Question how is the correct way how you give credits.
I just want to be on the safe Site.
For now I made a direct link to the Photo.

Here is the code :

`<img src="bild.jpg" alt="" width="400" height="500" title="a picture"> <div></div>`

```
<p title="Copyright">
     <a href="https://unsplash.com/photos/cMcake-xZVY">Link to the Picture</a></p>
```

Comment: This is not a coding question so I voted to close. However, the answer is that you can't use the pictures without permission, regardless of how you give credit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can add an element where on hover you can pop that up in which it is written that the owner of the picture is someone else and you want to give credit to them, another way is to take permission from that person to use the image in your website